# Why x and &x are same for arrays

Tags: c++, reference

Lets take a look at the example below

```
int x[10];
cout<<x<<endl;
cout<<&x<<endl; //both couts are same.


int x;
cout<<x<<endl;
cout<<&x<<endl; //last two couts are different.
```

What could be the reason for this?

Comment: Do you understand what the `&` is actually doing?

Comment: An array decomposes to a pointer to its first element. Taking the address of the array gives you the same pointer (with a different type). The second example is undefined behaviour.

Comment: @dunc123 yes, it is making a reference, which outputs the memory location of the variable,

Comment: @user1906399: It's making a pointer, not a reference. They are distinct (although similar) concepts in C++.

Answer (score 6):

In the first case,

```
cout << x << endl;
```

The array `x` decays to a pointer to its first element.  So you are seeing that address.  In the second case:

```
cout << &x << endl;
```

You are seeing the address of the array.  Which happens to be the same as the address of the array's first element, although it refers to a larger space encompassing *all* of the elements.  It doesn't necessarily have to print the same, but on your implementation (and every implementation I've ever worked with), it does.

When you're dealing with the single `int` in the next section, the first case doesn't decay to pointer, it just prints the value of the integer.  And when you change it to `&x`, you are explicitly asking for the address of that integer.

Comment: In the second case x has no value , then what value is it showing?

Comment: @user1906399: I didn't even realize you hadn't initialized it.  It's undefined behavior to access an uninitialized variable.  But in reality, it's just going to print whatever value happens to be in that location when the variable was declared.

Answer (score 4):

Because for an array `x[]`, it is equivalent to `&(x[0])` and which in turn is equivalent to `&x` as x is the pointer to the first element of the array.

Basically:

1. `x[0]` refers to the first element of an array.
2. `&(x[0])` gets the address of first element of array.
3. `x` is an array and printing `x` will result in the address of its first element.
4. `&x` refers to the address of an array.(NOTE: &x+1 and x+1 are different as former will point to location next to the end of an array and later will point to the second position of array)

Comment: More precisely, the *expression* `x` is implicitly converted to a pointer to `x[0]`, *unless* it's the operand of `&` or `sizeof`.

Comment: You should clarify what you mean by `=`. The array is not a pointer; but it is convertible to a pointer to its first element. `x` and `&x` point to the same memory location, but have different types. And the final statement is wrong: `x` is *not* a pointer.

Comment: Thanks all for the input. Did it in a hurry.

Comment: **2.** `&(x[0])` gets the address of the first element, that's the opposite of dereferencing. **3.** `x` is an array, not a pointer

Comment: @MikeSeymour: Tricky terminology. The *object* `x` is not a pointer object (it's an array object). The *expression* `x`, unless it's the operand of `&` or `sizeof`, evaluates to a pointer *value*. Still, saying "`x` is a pointer" without further qualification is misleading at best.

Answer (score 3):

An array variable all by itself without `[]` brackets decays to a pointer, i.e. it gets automatically converted to a pointer to the first element. The `&` makes a pointer explicitly.  Thus they're the same.

The `int` gets displayed directly, but the `&` makes a pointer again.  Thus they're different.

Answer (score 0):

Think about what you're actually doing.

```
int x[10];
cout<<x<<endl;
cout<<&x<<endl;
```

Here, `cout<<x<<endl;` will print &x because the value of x is the array's location in memory. Similarily `cout<<&x<<endl;` will also display &x.

```
int x;
cout<<x<<endl;
cout<<&x<<endl;
```

Now here, `cout<<x<<endl;` will print the value of x. Where as `cout<<&x<<endl;` will print the address of x.

If you would like to print the value of an array you need to use an accessor `cout<<x[0]<<endl;`